# MouseMove event keeps firing even when mouse is still

Tags: c#, winforms, mousemove

I want to know how exactly the MouseMove event works in c# windows form.

I'm making a windows form app and I was trying to make the function to move picturebox and list of label surrounding it with MouseMove event. It successfully moved everything as I expected but when I tried to move just labels, for some reason labels kept moving even is mouse if stopped.

The MouseMove event is assigned to the picturebox.

```cs
private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pbx = sender as PictureBox;
            if (down)
            {

//labels keeps moving without these two lines of codes below.
//They are the codes that moves PictureBox
                pbx.Left = e.X + pbx.Left - MouseLock.X;
                pbx.Top = e.Y + pbx.Top - MouseLock.Y;

                foreach(Label lbl in DisplayLabels)
                {
                    lbl.Left = e.X + lbl.Left - MouseLock.X;
                    lbl.Top = e.Y + lbl.Top - MouseLock.Y;
                }

                frm.label1.Text = e.X.ToString();
                frm.label2.Text = DisplayLabels[0].Left.ToString();
                frm.label3.Text = MouseLock.X.ToString();
                frm.label4.Text = sand.ToString();
                sand++;
            }
        }
```

I don't need to fix this issue since I got what I wanted but I want to know why it's happening.

Comment: can you show me the code where you are binding this event?

Comment: Also maybe show us the code where you set "down". Make sure you set it back to false or yes, they will keep moving.

Comment: A few years ago I was tracking the MouseMove event and I found that even without touching the mouse the event kept getting triggered, maybe just by someone walking by. In the end I stored the mouse position and only triggered my own "mouse move" code if it had moved x number of pixels. Not sure if this relates to your issue.

Comment: When you move the control, and the mouse is over it, then you do change the relative mouse position.  So it lets you know about it.  That then just keeps going with code like this.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797619/c-sharp-move-panel-horizontally-with-mousemove-event).

Comment: The mouse it still but the control isn't, so relatively the mouse isn't either.